# How to find what kinda-off xlsx package is available in the Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am totally confused on what kinda-off xlsx package is available in any installed Python?

Because for many scenario, it says openpyxl package not available for 2.7 or 3.1.1 or etc. And the solution the provide is to install the required package.

But its tough to install package just like that in an organization. So wanted to know the procedure to find what kinda of .xlsx package is installed in a particular Python.

For Eg:

For any import I do, like openpyxl, or xlsxwriter or xlwt etc, the result is same as given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "txttoxls.py", line 33, in <module>
    import openpyxl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Share in your comments!

Thanks!!

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Comment: Linux 3.0.101-84-default #1 SMP Tue Oct 18 10:32:51 UTC 2016 (15251d6) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Note:  I tried with python 2.7, 2.7.11, 3, 3.5.1, 3.6.1 and the result is same :-(

Comment: What is your distribution (distro)?

Comment: Linux version 3.0.101-84-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Tue Oct 18 10:32:51 UTC 2016 (15251d6)

Comment: Are you using python virtualenv?

Comment: Not sure about that, but I see a whole bunch of python versions installed. :-(
python*        python2.5.2*   python2.7*     python3.1.1*   python3.5.1*
python-config* python2.6*     python2.7.11*  python3.2.2*   python3.5.1a*
python2.3.4*   python2.6.1*   python2.7.5*   python3.3.1*   python3.6.1*
python2.4*     python2.6.2*   python2.7.9*   python3.3.2*   
python2.5*     python2.6.5*   python3*       python3.4.1*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148957/discussion-between-vix-and-vimo).